# CMD - Manually enter a value and check if it exists in a .txt with multiple lines > reply the result

Tags: cmd.exe, findstr, if

I am trying to create a batch file which will check a given term against an existing text file with multiple lines (10000+ lines).
More specifically, I have a list of domains that I want to blacklist, and I need to be able to run the batch file, enter the term that I want to seach in that file, and a reply to come back to me, if the term exists or not.

I am trying to combine the "if" command with "findstr" but because of my lack of understanding (yes, I am a noob in ) I am stuck.

For example, I end up to this so far, but it takes into account only the first line of the text file.

```
@echo off
set /p domain= < raw_list.txt
set /p string="Mention the domain that you want to check: "
echo %string% | findstr /c:"%domain%" > nul && ( echo found!! )
```

If someone can assist, it would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: set /p domain= < raw_list.txt - It only gets the first line of your text file. Use the ability of FINDSTR to search in file instead of string: echo %string% | findstr /G:raw_list.txt > nul && ( echo found!! )

Comment: Yeap! That works!
Thank you very much!

It shows up the "found" message.
Is there a way to output "not found" in case that the string is not present in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will only get the first line of your text file:

```
set /p domain= < raw_list.txt
```

Use this command instead in your pipe:

```
echo %string% | findstr /G:raw_list.txt > nul && ( echo found!! )
```

If you want to execute a different command when the string is found or not, you can check the ERRORLEVEL after the command is executed (I removed the echo and pipe to simplify but it will work also with your command):

```
findstr %string% "raw_list.txt" > nul 
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 ( echo found!! ) ELSE ( echo not found!! )
```

It's a best practice to always surround the path with double quotes (in case there is a space in path or file name). Also, I would suggest to use the full path if applicable.

Comment: That works perfectly! 
Thank you!

And if I need to print on the screen the results that were found?
Example... I am searching for "yahoo", it is found in the list, but I want to also see which versions of that "yahoo" is there. yahoo.com, yahoo.it, etc....

Comment: @Phantom My pleasure. If it's just to display it on screen, simply remove the *> nul* redirection to the *findstr* command.